# how to write a phptest for controller in fuelphp

Tags: php, phpunit, fuelphp

I only have a controller and view, I want to mock a http request to test this controller, I use fuelphp, hope someone can give me some advice or demo

```
class Controller_Index extends Controller_Template{
    public function action_index(){
        $view = View::forge('index');
        $this->template->content = $view;
    }
}
```

I write like this

```
class Test_Controller_index extends TestCase{
    public function TestController(){
        $expected = View::forge('index');
        $response = Request::forge('index')
                         ->set_method('GET')
                         ->execute()
                         ->response();
        $assertValue = $response->body->content;
        $this->assertSame($expected, $assertValue);
    }
}
```

php oil test result

```
There was 1 failure:
1) Warning
No tests found in class "Test_Controller_index".
```

what's wrong

Comment: it trouble me , hou can i make a request?

Comment: If you read your error message you'd see that the test framework is not picking up any tests. Try calling your test method `testController()` and see if that gets it to run.

Comment: Also I notice that you are only testing that the view loads. This kind of testing is useless as all you are doing is asserting that the framework can load a view, which is covered by the framework's own tests.

Comment: thanks for answering me ,acturally, i just want to mock a http request,because my project is broken,i have no db and some url jump is unused,so i want to do this mock.er..now i dont knoe whether  this is right or not,

Comment: i use fuelphp, why the  test method doesn't run as i hope?

Comment: There are plenty of ways that you can mock a http request, one would be to perform curl request against your application, however these are called "acceptance" tests and you should not be using PHPUnit to perform them. A quick google of "PHP acceptance test framework" can get you the information you need on those.

Comment: Your test might not be running simply because you need to name the method `testController` not `TestController`

Comment: thank you Uru,i have solved the problem,sometimes i got the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

All unit tests in fuelphp need to take the form of test_ or they won't be recognised.

Try this: (not the different function name)

```
class Test_Controller_index extends TestCase{
    public function test_controller(){
        $expected = View::forge('index');
        $response = Request::forge('index')
                         ->set_method('GET')
                         ->execute()
                         ->response();
        $assertValue = $response->body->content;
        $this->assertSame($expected, $assertValue);
    }
}
```